# Custom UITableViewCell with 3 labels

Tags: iphone, uitableview, label, title

I have a custom UITableViewCell and in it I have 2 labels. 
The 2 labels in the custom cell have name and location.

What I need to be able to do is, select a row and use the text in the name label of the row as the title for the next viewController.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on how you are drawing the cell.  Did you create a NIB based cell or are you using `drawRect` to draw one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the label in the cell a tag, like kMyNameLabelTag, when the cell is created.  When the cell is selected, use cellForRowAtIndexPath to get the cell then viewWithTag to get the label in the cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *theName = [(UILabel *)[[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] contentView] viewWithTag:kMyNameLabelTag] text];
}
```

This assumes you added the labels to the contentView.

Comment: In addition to the above response, you may find some useful information for communicating between view controllers here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569940/whats-the-best-way-to-communicate-between-view-controllers/575497#575497

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using this code:

```
anotherViewController.navigationItem.title= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"Patient No: ", patient.ID];
```

Thanks for the suggestions.