# What's the best way to reverse communicate between view controllers?

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, controllers

I've been thinking about this and have read through another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569940/whats-the-best-way-to-communicate-between-view-controllers) regarding the best recommended way to communicate between view controllers. However, the question/answer for that doesn't seem to address the best approach for the reverse behavior.

i.e. to pass data from `ParentController` to its `ModalController`, we could initialize `ModalController` like `initWithDataToProcess:`.

But what if we want to do the **reverse**? How would I notify the previous controller about a new data?

e.g. User clicks on 'new person' button on the `ParentController`. I initiate a new `ModalController` and present the user with a person editor view via `presentModalViewController:`. User clicks on 'done' to add a new person. I `dismissModalViewController:` and UI returns to the `ParentController`'s view.

Using a global *field* reference in a singleton object (app delegate or other) is bad. *delegation* (via formal protocol) and *notifications* (via NSNotificationCenter) seems overkill. Any suggestions?

Comment: In .NET land, it's not an issue since a modal call (`ShowDialog()`) is a blocking call. Doesn't seem to be the case with Objective-c/Cocoa with `presentModalViewController:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally cleaner to use notifications. Just add your observer like this....

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(somethingHappened:) name:@"MyNotification" object:nil];
```

and elsewhere in your code you'd post the notification whenever you need to.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyNotification" object:self];
```

In the example I'm passing self but you can pass any object you wish really and it will be fed to your somethingHappened: function

The important thing is to keep the @"MyNotification" very descriptive and unique. Adding your project name to the beginning is a good way to keep things unique...eg. @"ProjAXViewHasGotData"

Answer (score 0):

A delegate is pretty much the minimum you can do. If you think it is too much of a hassle to declare a new protocol for this, just pass in the parent view controller and have the modal one call a method on it.

Comment: *HOW* do you "just pass it"... and "have the modal one call it"? ( Why do so many people answer questions with "you do it... just by doing it"... instead of telling *HOW* you do it?)