# Passing a Value Through a Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, variables, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm looking to pass a user chosen value from one view to the next so it can be submitted to Twitter, Facebook, etc.

Would a global variable be best to implement? I don't want the value to be stored or saved anywhere.. just to make it through the end of the navigation controller (submission to Facebook, Twitter, etc.)

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**Header File**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ShareViewController.h"
#include "TwitterRushViewController.h"

@interface KindViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
            IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
            IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
            BOOL pageControlIsChangingPage;

            CLLocationManager *locationManager;
            NSString *finalCoordinates;
            NSString *finalChoice;
            }

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPageControl *pageControl;

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager; 
@property (retain) NSString *finalCoordinates;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *finalChoice;


-(IBAction)changePage:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)submitChoice:(id)sender;
-(void)setupPage;

@end
```

**Implementation File**

```
#import "KindViewController.h"
#import "JSON/JSON.h"

@implementation KindViewController
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize pageControl;
@synthesize locationManager;
@synthesize finalCoordinates;
@synthesize finalChoice;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIView boilerplate
- (void)viewDidLoad {   
    [self setupPage];   
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Alert the User on Location Access
    self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    }

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];    
    }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    CLLocation *location = newLocation;
    NSLog(@"Our current Latitude is %f", location.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"Our current Longitude is %f", location.coordinate.longitude);
    NSString *Coordinates = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Longitude=%f&Latitude=%f", location.coordinate.longitude, location.coordinate.latitude ];
    NSLog(@"Test: %@", Coordinates);
    finalCoordinates = Coordinates;
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; 
    }

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark The Guts
- (void)setupPage {
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    [scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    NSUInteger nimages = 0;
    CGFloat cx = 0;
    for (; ; nimages++) {
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"choice%d.png", (nimages + 1)];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        if (image == nil) {
            break;
        }
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
        rect.size.height = image.size.height;
        rect.size.width = image.size.width;
        rect.origin.x = ((scrollView.frame.size.width - image.size.width) / 2) + cx;
        rect.origin.y = ((scrollView.frame.size.height - image.size.height) / 2);

        imageView.frame = rect;

        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];

        cx += scrollView.frame.size.width;
    }
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = nimages;
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cx, [scrollView bounds].size.height)];
    }


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate stuff
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView {
    if (pageControlIsChangingPage) {
        return;
    }
    CGFloat pageWidth = _scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((_scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    pageControl.currentPage = page;
    }

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView {
    pageControlIsChangingPage = NO;
    }


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PageControl stuff
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender {
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * pageControl.currentPage;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
    pageControlIsChangingPage = YES;
    }


-(IBAction)submitChoice:(id)sender; {

    // Spinner
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(135,140,50,50)];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];

    // Find the Date
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm"];

    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSString *dateString = [format stringFromDate:now];

    // Echo Everything
    NSLog(@"Type is %f.", scrollView.contentOffset.x);
    NSLog(@"Date is %@", dateString);
    NSLog(@"Coordinates are %@", finalCoordinates);

    NSString *completeURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"http://www.example.com/insert.php?Type=%f&Time=%@&%@", scrollView.contentOffset.x, dateString, finalCoordinates];
    NSString *escapedUrl = [completeURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"URL is %@.", escapedUrl);

    // Post to Web Server
    NSURL *urlToSend = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:escapedUrl];
    NSLog(@"NSURL is %@.", urlToSend);

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlToSend cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:30];

    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    // Do the Button Action
    ShareViewController *shareViewController = [[ShareViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShareViewController" bundle:nil];
    shareViewController.finalChoice = @"Facebook Property";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:shareViewController animated:YES];
    [shareViewController release];

    [urlToSend release];
    [completeURL release];
    [spinner release];
    }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"There is an error updating the location");
    }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    }

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [pageControl release];
    }

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    }

@end
```

**ShareViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "SA_OAuthTwitterController.h" 
#import "FBConnect/FBConnect.h"
#import "TwitterRushViewController.h"
#import "oAuth2TestViewController.h"

@class SA_OAuthTwitterEngine;

@interface ShareViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, SA_OAuthTwitterControllerDelegate> {
    }

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *shareFacebookBTN;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *shareTwitterBTN;
@property (nonatomic, retain) KindViewController finalChoice;


/* Submissions */
- (IBAction)shareNoThanks:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)shareFacebook:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)shareTwitter:(id)sender;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just setting a property on the next UIViewController when you push it would probably be the easiest thing to do.

```
SomeViewController *someViewController = [[SomeViewController alloc] init];
someViewController.facebookProperty = @"Facebook Property";
someViewController.twitterProperty = @"Twitter Property";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
[someViewController release];
```

Ok there are a few things wrong with ShareViewController.h. First if you have a property you also need to have an instance variable for that property. Next you are assigning a string to finalChoice but you have declared its type as KindViewController it should be NSString.

In ShareViewController.h

```
@interface ShareViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, SA_OAuthTwitterControllerDelegate> {
    NSString *finalChoice;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *shareFacebookBTN;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *shareTwitterBTN;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *finalChoice;
```

And make sure you @synthesize finalChoice in your implementation file.

Comment: Thanks Aaron! How do I call this in the next view? Do I use a @synthesize?

Comment: Yeah they should be defined as properties in SomeViewController e.g. have an instance variable called NSString *facebookProperty and a property @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *facebookProperty. You should then synthesize it in the implementation file.

Comment: Hi Aaron... thanks! That's exactly what I have in my file.. but I'm getting the following error "Request for member "facebookProperty" in something not a structure or union." I edited my answer to include my code.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure, something strange is going on there. I would suggest simplifying what you have and seeing if you can get it to work. If you still have no luck then maybe post more code.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure it out... but I've updated my answer to include my entire implementation file.

Comment: Would you be able to post the header file for ShareViewController?

Comment: Sorry I wanted to see the header file for ShareViewController just to see how the property is getting defined etc

Comment: I think that's my problem. I attached the Header file above.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing any of the specifics, I would avoid a global variable or tightly coupling the two views together.

Depending on your needs and implementation, [delegation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) or [notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) may a better choice to pass a variable between views.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good discussion on the more general problem of how best to communicate between view controllers [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569940/whats-the-best-way-to-communicate-between-view-controllers). The top-voted answer is pretty good.

The tl;dr version is basically:

1. Global variables and singleton classes are rarely the right answer.
2. Read up on the "dependency injection" design pattern.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks zbrimhall! I'll take a closer look.