# Pass values from a UIViewController to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

before the closing of my FlipsideViewController I have these values

```
shours
sminutes
sseconds
srecharge
change
```

from the declaration

```
int shours;
int sminutes;
int sseconds;
int srecharge;
bool change;
```

Now I want to pass these variables to another UIViewController (MainViewController) in these other variables

```
mhours
mminutes
mseconds
mrecharge
mchange
```

What's the simplest method to do this?

Comment: Instead of an object, you could just do ints or what ever data type you are using. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/ios5-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872472/how-to-pass-a-textfiled-value-from-one-view-to-any-other-view-xcode

Comment: I3v the problem is that I want to pass variables from the second View, so the segue are not good.

Comment: Suresh I'm not able to apply what's said in your link

Comment: Got you a complete example below.  Passing your own custom object is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom object property on your `MainViewController` and set it on your `FlipsideViewController` or you can't do it for some reason: Create an object to hold these values and put it into `NSUserDefaults` and read on `MainViewController`.

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myObject forKey:@"myObjectKey"]

Comment: I want to pass int values and a bool, not NSString

Comment: As I've mentioned: you should create an object to hold the ints and bools. Or you can store the one by one in an NSNumber ([NSNumber numberwithInt:/numberWithBool:]

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create a "Model" class that holds those vars and pass the model class from one view controller to the next. Once it's linked in view1 & view2 during transition from view1 to view2, then it's automatically updated when transitioning back from view2 to view1. Use @property (assign) int shours so you have setters and getters created.

With this approach, using segues will work just fine. You don't need to use NSUserDefaults or NSNotificationCenter.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class to hold these values.  Then pass this object between view controllers.

Something like this:

Interface file:

```
//
//  MyObject.h
//  SOObjectPassing
//
//  Created by Wilson, LJ on 11/15/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Arkansas Children's Hospital. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyObject : NSObject {
    int shours;
    int sminutes;
    int sseconds;
    int srecharge;
    bool change;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int shours;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int sminutes;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int sseconds;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int srecharge;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL change;

-(id) initWithHours:(int)hours
            minutes:(int)minutes
            seconds:(int)seconds
           recharge:(int)recharge
             changed:(BOOL)changed;

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
//
//  MyObject.m
//  SOObjectPassing
//
//  Created by Wilson, LJ on 11/15/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Arkansas Children's Hospital. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MyObject.h"


@implementation MyObject
@synthesize shours = _shours;
@synthesize sminutes = _sminutes;
@synthesize sseconds = _sseconds;
@synthesize srecharge = _srecharge;
@synthesize change = _change;

-(id) initWithHours:(int)hours
            minutes:(int)minutes
            seconds:(int)seconds
           recharge:(int)recharge
             changed:(BOOL)changed {

    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _shours = hours;
        _sminutes = minutes;
        _sseconds = seconds;
        _srecharge = recharge;
        _change = changed;
    }

    return self;
}
@end
```

And instantiate your object like this:

```
MyObject *myObject = [[MyObject alloc] initWithHours:2
                                                 minutes:3
                                                 seconds:4
                                                recharge:1
                                                 changed:NO];
```

Then just pass that entire object to your other VC (s).

[Here is a sample project illustrating this.](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3660978/SOObjectPassing.zip)