# sending data from DetailViewController to MasterViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, didselectrowatindexpath, message-passing

This is what exactly I'm trying to do.

wizardviewcontroller.m

```
- (IBAction)onCountryClick:(id)sender {
    MJDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[MJDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MJDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentPopupViewController:detailViewController animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideLeftRight];
}
```

User click country button a popup shows with list.

when user select a row button title should change.

This is my detailview,

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {

    WizardViewController *mj = [[WizardViewController alloc]       initWithNibName:@"WizardViewController" bundle:nil];
    mj.countryselected = [countryNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [mj.countryButton setTitle:mj.countryselected forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self dismissPopupViewControllerWithanimationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];
}
```

`DetailViewController` is dismissing, but `countryButtonTitle` is not updating. I know this is because the wizardview is not refreshing. I would like to know the correct workaround in this case.

Hope this helps to get better answer.

Comment: Your code creates a *new* instance of WizardViewController and sets a property on that new instance. You have to set the properties of your *existing* master view controller.

Comment: my master view controller is WizardViewController

Comment: Not exactly...it's **an instance of a** WizardViewController.  When you create a new one, it's a different object.

Comment: You should use protocol in detail view and set master as delegate.
See Utility app for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to communicate between view controllers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569940/whats-the-best-way-to-communicate-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make Protocol in `MJDetailViewController`

```
@protocol MJDetailViewControllerDelegate;
@interface MJDetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,assign) id< MJDetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end


@protocol MJDetailViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)selectedContry:(NSString *)title;

@end
```

And call like

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {

    NSString *title = [countryNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedContry:)]) {
            [self.delegate selectedContry:title];
        }
    [self dismissPopupViewControllerWithanimationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];
}
```

Add `MJDetailViewControllerDelegate` as a `protocol` in `WizardViewController.h`)

Now implement `selectedContry:` method in `WizardViewController.m` like:

```
- (void)selectedContry:(NSString *)title
{
    [self.countryButton setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: +1 Nice Answer, I have done some editing. I hope you won't mind.