# Reference BOOL of Different View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, boolean, viewcontroller

In my project, I've declared a BOOL *isOn in my FirstViewController. In FirstViewController, I have two buttons where pressing buttonOne, sets isOn to YES, and buttonTwo sets isOn to NO. In my SecondViewController, I'm trying to run an if-statement that references the status of isOn. I'm getting error "Assigning to 'readonly' return result of an Objective-C not allowed". How may I get my desired intent?

```
//FirstViewController.h

@property (assign) BOOL isOn;

- (IBAction)buttonOne:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)buttonTwo:(id)sender;


//FirstViewController.m

- (IBAction)buttonOne:(id)sender {  
[self setIsOn:YES];
}

- (IBAction)offSiteButton:(id)sender {
[self setIsOn:NO];
}

//SecondViewController.m

#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "FirstViewController.m"

FirstViewController *FVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {

if ([FVC isOn] = YES) {  <----Error

// Do this

} else {

// Do that

}
```

If I just run it with...

```
if ([FVS isOn])
```

The if-statement returns the else function and 'does that' for both buttons. Please help.

Comment: i wont think this would work. even with '==' operator.
just nslog vc.isOn and i think it will display nil

Comment: You're right, but can you offer any ideas to get it to work as I intend?

Comment: You should probably read [What's the best way to communicate between view controllers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569940/whats-the-best-way-to-communicate-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 4):

The compiler error is because you forgot an equals sign, it should be

```
if ([FVC isOn] == YES)
```

with that said though, `[FVS isOn]` is equivalent to that, so your problem with it only running `Do that` doesn't lie there. There isn't enough code to figure out why that is happening: are you sure that FVC has been set to the correct value?

Comment: Good observation but the result of my if-statement remains. You may be right about FVC though. How would I declare that in my SecondViewController viewDidLoad? Assigning FVC = FirstViewController in viewDidLoad does not do the trick.

Comment: Where do you get the reference to firstViewController? Are you making a new one inside of viewDidLoad by calling an init method? Assuming that your IBAction Methods are actually firing and that nothing else is setting isOn, the only other explanation I can see is that you don't actually have a pointer to the right instance of FirstViewController.

Comment: i have added my answer below.. please check

Answer (score 1):

try:
 if(FVC.isOn == YES)
Remember when you want to compare values you use == operator.

Comment: That's true but the if-statement still returns else. See comment to Ben's answer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboards , you can pass the value from the first view controller to the secondViewController using

in ViewController:h

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ():UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isOn;

-(IBAction)button:(UIButton *) button;
-(IBAction)go;

@end
```

In ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize isOn;

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    [vc setIsOn:isOn];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(IBAction)button:(UIButton *)button
{
    switch (button.tag) {
        case 1:
        [self setIsOn:YES];
        break;

        case 2:
        [self setIsOn:NO];
        break;
      }
 }

-(IBAction)go
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"next" sender:nil];
}
```

and in SecondViewController.h

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isOn;

@end
```

in SecondViewController.m

```
@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize isOn;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
 {
      self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
      if (self) {
          // Custom initialization
      }
      return self;
  }

- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     if (isOn == YES)
     {
          NSLog(@"Hello");
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"exit");
     }
  }
```

Comment: note that ibaction button  is the action for both the buttons in the first view controller

Comment: will mail you the complete code i tried if you give me your mail id

Comment: yes please, jb12apps@gmail.com

Comment: I got your email. It's not working because in my project it goes; FirstVC ----> (tabbarcontroller) [SecondVC, ThirdVC]. So I'm getting error "-[TabBarViewController setIsOnSite:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance " Sorry I should have made that known. Do you have a suggestion to get around this? Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Your code has 'no issues' initially but then terminates app when I push button for seque. I'll play around with a bit.

Comment: did you 'embed in' navigation controller to the view controller after the tab bar controller

Comment: No, there is no navigation controller. Just a single-view (FirstVC) controller sequed to a tabbarcontroller (SecondVC, ThirdVC).

Comment: I've successful passed information between SecondVC and ThirdVC within the tabbarcontroller, but I can't pass anything between FirstVC and SecondVC. Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: You can do it the same way as you did it in the SecondVC to ThirdVC